# Parameter only work in conjunction with others but I want them to work independently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I have the following script:

```
DECLARE @PlanId NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @PlanName NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionID NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionDescription01 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionDescription02 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionDescription03 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionDescription04 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @ActionDescription05 NVARCHAR(255) = ''

select ap.plan_id ,ap.plan_name ,apa.action_id ,apa.action_description
from dbo.ACTION_PLAN ap
LEFT JOIN ACTION_PLAN_LINK AS apl ON apl.PLAN_ID = ap.PLAN_ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ACTION_PLAN_ACTION AS apa ON apa.ACTION_ID = apl.ACTION_ID
WHERE
    (ap.PLAN_ID = @PlanId or @PlanId = '')
and (ap.PLAN_NAME = @PlanName or @PlanName = '')
and (apa.ACTION_ID = @ActionID or @ActionID = '')
and ( 
      ( (len(@ActionDescription01)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription01+ '%') ) )
   or ( (len(@ActionDescription02)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription02+ '%') ) )
   or ( (len(@ActionDescription03)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription03+ '%') ) )
   or ( (len(@ActionDescription04)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription04+ '%') ) )
   or ( (len(@ActionDescription05)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription05+ '%') ) )
    )
```

The above script works fine when searching using action descriptions but doesn't allow me to only search a plan_id, plan_name or action_id. I would like to be able to search for any one or combination of the parameters. I would also like to add the reason I used the or operator in the action description where clause to bring more results for each action searched for. For example, I search for plan_id 100, I then enter 'inform' in the actiondescription01 and I get one result, I then enter 'order' in the the actiondescription02 parameter and I get 3 results as there are two pertaining to order and the one pertaining to inform but they are all part of the one plan_id (if a plan_id is entered).

I hope this makes sense and someone can assist. The above script works exactly as I want but for some reason I am unable to search for a PlanId, PlanName or ActionId independently but they work if I search in conjunction with an action description parameter.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more `(` `)` than you need
The `and (    (` is killing it.  If none or the `or` in that group are true then that `and` is false.

```
select ap.plan_id ,ap.plan_name ,apa.action_id,  apa.action_description
from dbo.ACTION_PLAN ap
LEFT JOIN ACTION_PLAN_LINK AS apl       ON apl.PLAN_ID   = ap.PLAN_ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ACTION_PLAN_ACTION AS apa ON apa.ACTION_ID = apl.ACTION_ID
WHERE (ap.PLAN_ID    = @PlanId   or @PlanId = '')
  and (ap.PLAN_NAME  = @PlanName or @PlanName = '')
  and (apa.ACTION_ID = @ActionID or @ActionID = '')
  and (    ( len(@ActionDescription01) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription01 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription02) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription02 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription03) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription03 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription04) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription04 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription05) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription05 + '%') ) 
      )
```

fix

```
and (      ( len(@ActionDescription01) = 0 and len(@ActionDescription02) = 0 ...)
        or ( len(@ActionDescription01) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription01 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription02) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription02 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription03) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription03 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription04) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription04 + '%' ) 
        or ( len(@ActionDescription05) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription05 + '%') ) 
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change these lines

```
or ( (len(@ActionDescription02)>1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @ActionDescription02+ '%') ) )
```

To something like this

```
or (
    len(@ActionDescription02)=0 
    or ( len(@ActionDescription02)>0 
         and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like '%' + @ActionDescription02+ '%' )
   )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this doesn't work as if I only populate one parameter, the criteria for len(actiondescription02)=0 is always fulfilled.

Comment: @msinghm No, you have to repeat this construction for any parameter. You have to check for *the parameter is not set OR it is set AND fullfills a condition*.

Comment: I cannot use the AND operator as I want to be able to search on multiple actiondescription (up to but not always all 5) increasing the resulting dataset each time. In my example above using inform and order, the actions including those words are on different rows but pertain to the same plan. Using AND would return results that fulfil both criteria.